# MapKit: Route not being displayed between two annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swiftui, swift5

Im trying to display a route between two annotations.

The annotations and the region work fine but the route won't show up and I have no idea why
It looks like the route is not being rendered at all.
I'm sure that the route exists because I tried to print it and it is in the `directionResponse.routes`
Any suggestions?

I'm using SwiftUI

Then this is included in a parent view.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import FirebaseFirestore

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var packageLocation: GeoPoint
    var destination: GeoPoint
    var driverLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView()
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = .blue
        renderer.lineWidth = 2.0
        return renderer
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        let requestLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: packageLocation.latitude, longitude: packageLocation.longitude)
        let destinationLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destination.latitude, longitude: destination.longitude)

        //let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1)
        //let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: requestLocation, span: span)
        //uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = requestLocation
        annotation.title = "Package Title"
        uiView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        let annotation2 = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation2.coordinate = destinationLocation
        annotation2.title = "Destiantion"
        uiView.addAnnotation(annotation2)

        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: requestLocation)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation)


        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

        directions.calculate { (response, error) in
            guard let directionResponse = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                return
            }
            print(directionResponse)

            let route = directionResponse.routes[0]
            uiView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            uiView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost got it.

The one issue that you need to resolve is the use of the `MKMapView` delegate functions.

The easiest way to do that is to subclass `MKMapView` and make your own map view that has conforms to `MKMapViewDelegate`.

Firstly, create your own map view, subclassing `MKMapView` and conforming to `MKMapViewDelegate`. At the moment you're only really using the `rendererFor overlay` delegate method so I'll just implement that, but you can add other methods if you require them.

```swift
class WrappableMapView: MKMapView, MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = .red
        renderer.lineWidth = 4.0
        return renderer
    }
}
```

Then you need to update your `UIViewRepresentable` to use the new `WrappableMapView` that you just created. I have gone for making a functional example, so here I am passing in the request and destination locations. You can handle this how you want but at least this will give you something that works.

```swift
struct MyMapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var requestLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    @Binding var destinationLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    private let mapView = WrappableMapView()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyMapView>) -> WrappableMapView {
        mapView.delegate = mapView // make sure we set our delegate to be the mapView we just created
        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WrappableMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MyMapView>) {

        let requestAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        requestAnnotation.coordinate = requestLocation
        requestAnnotation.title = "Package Title"
        uiView.addAnnotation(requestAnnotation)

        let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        destinationAnnotation.coordinate = destinationLocation
        destinationAnnotation.title = "Destination"
        uiView.addAnnotation(destinationAnnotation)

        let requestPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: requestLocation)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation)

        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: requestPlacemark)
        directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
        directionRequest.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculate { response, error in
            guard let response = response else { return }

            let route = response.routes[0]
            uiView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            uiView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)

            // if you want insets use this instead of setRegion
            //  uiView.setVisibleMapRect(rect, edgePadding: .init(top: 50.0, left: 50.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 50.0), animated: true)
        }

    }
}
```

Finally we can put it all together with a `ContentView` that shows it works:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var requestLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.509865, longitude:  -0.118092)
    @State var destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.501266, longitude: -0.093210)

    var body: some View {
        MyMapView(requestLocation: $requestLocation, destinationLocation: $destinationLocation)
    }
}
```

This is what it should look like:

[image: Map View with route]

---

One thing to note, using the `rendererFor overlay` delegate function in the simulator causes an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445093/compiler-error-invalid-library-file-corelocation). This only happens in the simulator and not on device, so don't be surprised if you see an error message like this in the console.

```
2019-11-08 18:50:30.034066+0000 StackOverflow[80354:9526181] Compiler error: Invalid library file
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, do you know how to add a span to `MKCoordinateRegion` so they don't display at the edge of the screen?

Comment: Yup I have added an alternative to the end of `updateUIView`