# SwiftUI console showing CVDisplayLink related messages?

Tags: swiftui

I'm getting a lot of output on the console as I run a MacOS based SwiftUI app I'm developing, for example:

```
2021-12-08 12:40:14.439565+0000 SpDriveApp[6801:159299] [] [0x7fe6e7830820] CVCGDisplayLink::setCurrentDisplay: 1892262333
2021-12-08 12:40:14.439785+0000 SpDriveApp[6801:159299] [] [0x7fe6e7830800] CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplays count: 1 [displayID[0]: 0x70c9a1bd] [CVCGDisplayLink: 0x7fe6e7830820]
2021-12-08 12:40:14.439827+0000 SpDriveApp[6801:159299] [] [0x7fe6e7830800] CVDisplayLinkStart
2021-12-08 12:40:14.439853+0000 SpDriveApp[6801:159299] [] [0x7fe6e7830820] CVDisplayLink::start
2021-12-08 12:40:14.439993+0000 SpDriveApp[6801:182706] [] [0x60000f698460] CVXTime::reset
```

Has anyone else seen this? Have I accidentally switched on a diagnostic tool, or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Im also seeing this since installing macOS 12.1. I have Core Data logging (`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` and `-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1`). Only just noticed this myself, perhaps worth logging a feedback.

Comment: I'm seeing `CVDisplayLink` and `CVCGDisplayLink` messages that present in console when I scroll within a `ScrollView` (macOS target only).

Comment: Seeing this as well. I filed a feedback report about it: FB9810620

Answer (score 6):

I get these messages not because of SwiftUI, but because of a WKWebView, nevertheless this work around may work for both:

Add the 'Environment Variable': `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`, with value: `disable` on `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit Scheme` > `Run` > `Arguments`.

[image: Editing the scheme to add environment variable]

Comment: This "works", but it disables everything, from spam to useful warnings, autolayout errors, and my own logging.

Comment: @Guilmo it should not be the case. Most logs and warnings should still be visible, specially your own ones. Check that you haven't accidentally set a filter on the console (bottom right corner), otherwise restart Xcode and try some logging again.

Comment: More information here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39651073/568462 tldr try using 'default' instead of 'disable'

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an alternative, more granular solution to using `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`, but this one is global to your macOS installation. I found this on Daniel Jakult's blog [Indie Stack](https://indiestack.com/2022/03/quieting-cvdisplaylink-logging/):

You can disable these messages by running this in your terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.corevideo cv_note 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to remove unused import which was automatically added by Xcode

import CloudKit

Comment: Nop, I wasn't right. It's not an answer